# Maximum Rented car name

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT c.car_name,
       MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 AS No_of_Days,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 DESC) as Dense_Rank
FROM cars AS c
JOIN rentals AS r ON c.car_id = r.car_id
WHERE MONTH(pickup_date) = 5
GROUP BY c.car_id
ORDER BY Dense_Rank;
```

Error is

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 80: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the m anual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
> the right syntax to use near (ORDER BY
> MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date,r.pickup_date))+1 DESC) as Dense_Rank from
> at line 2

Comment: can you add more info how data is related and sample data

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using `Dense_Rank` as a column name which isn't allowed as it is a reserved keyword, always if you are using a MySQL version which support window functions

Answer (score 0):

With the data like here:

```sql
/*    S a m p l e    D a t a :
cars table
CAR_ID  CAR_NAME
------  --------
     1  VOLVO
     2  BMW
     3  RENAULT

rentals table
CAR_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE
------  ----------  -----------
     1  2023-11-11  2023-11-11
     1  2023-11-12  2023-11-17
     1  2023-11-20  2023-11-30
     2  2023-11-11  2023-11-14
     2  2023-11-15  2023-11-17
     3  2023-11-01  2023-11-14      */
```

... you could create a CTE (grid) to get days of rental per car and max number of days over all.

```sql
--  S Q L :
WITH   
  grid AS
    ( SELECT r.CAR_NAME, r.DIFF, MAX(r.DIFF) OVER() "MAX_DIFF"
      FROM ( Select c.CAR_ID, c.CAR_NAME,
                    Sum(r.END_DATE - r.START_DATE + 1) Over(Partition By c.CAR_ID) "DIFF"
             From   cars c
             Join  rentals r ON(r.CAR_ID = c.CAR_ID)
           ) r
      GROUP BY r.CAR_NAME, r.DIFF
      ORDER BY r.DIFF Desc
    )
/*  --  R e s u l t :  (grid)
CAR_NAME      DIFF  MAX_DIFF
----------  ------  --------
VOLVO           18        18
RENAULT         14        18
BMW              7        18    */
```

...with the above resultset you can get the most rented car ...

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT g.CAR_NAME, g.DIFF
FROM   grid g
WHERE  g.DIFF = g.MAX_DIFF;
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CAR_NAME      DIFF  
----------  ------  
VOLVO           18  */
```

... see it at --> https://dbfiddle.uk/B0EAwnW7

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax error encountered,it's because you used `dense_rank`(which the query parser resolves as a window function) for alias. Please refrain from doing so to avoid confusion. If you must use it, enclose them with backtick, which is MySQL's identifier quote character:

```
SELECT c.car_name,
       MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 AS No_of_Days,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 DESC) as `Dense_Rank`
FROM cars AS c
JOIN rentals AS r ON c.car_id = r.car_id
WHERE MONTH(pickup_date) = 5
GROUP BY c.car_id
ORDER BY `Dense_Rank`;
```

Comment: This errors @blabla_bingo for grouping by not selected column - when corrected then it returns longest particular rental period per car. The OP asks for max rented car name...

Answer (score -1):

is this query will result the same error?

```
SELECT c.car_name,
       MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 AS No_of_Days,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 DESC) as Dense_Rank
FROM cars AS c
JOIN rentals AS r ON c.car_id = r.car_id
WHERE MONTH(pickup_date) = 5
GROUP BY c.car_id
ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query

```
SELECT a.car_name,
   a.No_of_Days,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.No_of_Days DESC) as Dense_Rank
FROM(
SELECT c.car_name,(MAX(DATEDIFF(r.return_date, r.pickup_date)) + 1) AS 
No_of_Days
FROM cars AS c
JOIN rentals AS r ON c.car_id = r.car_id
WHERE MONTH(pickup_date) = 5
GROUP BY c.car_id) a
ORDER BY Dense_Rank;
```